# My Lua 5.1 Implementation of the OPCODE TFORLOOP is not working correctly

Tags: lua, lua-5.1

I am working on a Lua 5.1 VM inside of Lua 5.1. Most Opcodes work fine but my TFORLOOP does not work. I get this error:
Bad Argument #1 to '?' (table expected, got function)

Here is my implementation of TFORLOOP:

```
        [33] = function(INSTRUCTION) --TFORLOOP
            local offset = INSTRUCTION.a + 3
            local result = {stack[INSTRUCTION.a](stack[INSTRUCTION.a], stack[INSTRUCTION.a + 1], stack[INSTRUCTION.a + 2])}
            for i = 1, INSTRUCTION.c do
                stack[offset + i - 1] = result[i]
            end
        
            if result[1] ~= nil then
                stack[INSTRUCTION.a + 1] = result[1]
            else
                if result[2] ~= nil then
                    stack[INSTRUCTION.a + 1] = result[2]
                else
                    pc = pc + 1
                end
            end
        end,
```

And I parse these instructions:

```
{a=0,op=5,Bx=0,}
{a=1,op=10,c=0,b=10,}
{a=2,op=1,Bx=1,}
{a=3,op=1,Bx=2,}
{a=4,op=1,Bx=3,}
{a=5,op=1,Bx=4,}
{a=6,op=1,Bx=5,}
{a=7,op=1,Bx=6,}
{a=8,op=1,Bx=7,}
{a=9,op=1,Bx=8,}
{a=10,op=1,Bx=9,}
{a=11,op=1,Bx=10,}
{a=1,op=34,c=1,b=10,}
{a=0,op=28,c=4,b=2,}
{a=0,op=22,sBx=3,}
{a=5,op=5,Bx=11,}
{a=6,op=0,c=0,b=4,}
{a=5,op=28,c=1,b=2,}
{a=0,op=33,c=2,b=0,}
{a=0,op=22,sBx=-5,}
{a=0,op=30,c=0,b=1,}
```

Constants:

```
pairs
print
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Thanks!

To help me understand why my TFORLOOP OPCODE is not working and maybe fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`TFORLOOP`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lopcodes.h.html#OP_TFORLOOP) must calculate `R(A)(R(A+1), R(A+2))`
You are calculating `R(A)(R(A), R(A+1), R(A+2))` instead